# Name for an independent domain/hostname

Tags: http, dns, subdomain

Anyone know what the correct term is for a minimal (IP) domain name which intuitively indicates a domain registered through "typical" channels?

E.g., the term would indicate
 - `google.com`
 - `bbc.co.uk`

But not:
 - `www.google.com`
 - `code.google.com`
 - `co.uk`

(The term *second-level domain* doesn't quite work beacuse of the latter counter-example, where `co.` is the second-level domain name hosted within the `.uk` country code top-level domain. Maybe such a term does not exist?)

---

**EDIT** Hmm... can't self-answer for another 6 hours. Boo.

AFAICS, there's no concrete/authoritative term.

In [The Art of SEO By Eric Enge, Stephan Spencer, Rand Fishkin, Jessie C. Stricchiola](http://books.google.ie/books?id=4VvOLL4KIesC&pg=PA202&lpg=PA202&dq=pay%20level%20domain&source=bl&ots=etpsps4Zdc&sig=LcXR7EEv_DLZyiTOe6jAtNJiXKM&hl=en&ei=I09ITqnUMoyYhQexzZWwBg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=3&ved=0CEEQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=pay%20level%20domain&f=false), they use terms like *complete root domain/host domain/pay-level domain/second-level domain*. As far as I can see, none of these terms is standard, and the latter term is actually strictly incorrect/ambiguous. Similar discussion is available on [this page](http://www.seomoz.org/blog/what-the-heck-should-we-call-domaincom).

nist.gov use the term *enterprise-level domain*, but again it's equated with second-level domain and used conflictingly in [this report](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistpubs/800-81r1/sp-800-81r1.pdf) for third/fourth/etc. level domains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Mozilla Foundation uses the term [Public Suffix](http://www.publicsuffix.org) to describe domains that can be registered through typical channels, which it defines to include `.com`, `.co.uk`, and `pvt.k12.wy.us`.  The usage of this terminology may not be standard, however.

Edit: The [Wikipedia entry on the Public Suffix list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_Suffix_List) uses the term "effective top level domain", which appears to describe this concept, although it doesn't appear to be in widespread use.

Comment: That's a useful link... I think we actually use this list. This page: http://publicsuffix.org/learn/ seems to suggest that there is no name for what I'm on about, nor even a clear definition. (will accept later if no other answers come through)

Answer (score 1):

The term 'second-level' is correct for google.com and 'third-level' for bbc.co.uk.

The country specific TLD is ccTLD.

The 'co' in 'co.uk' is termed 'generic-category 2nd level'.

Full details on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_name)

Comment: Apologies if you're correct, but "co.uk" is a cc*S*LD: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CcSLD ...would this not make "bbc.co.uk" a third-level domain? From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_name "Next are third-level domains, which are written immediately to the left of a second-level domain". Confusing :).

Comment: You are correct, I updated my answer -- and learned something new today :)

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure what you mean by "typical" channels, but I'll explain in general a few terms you might find handy:

**Top Level Domains** (TLDs) are domains that end in .com, .net, .org, or other "major" suffixes. This includes major country endings such as .uk and .us The full list is here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains

**Subdomains** are best explained by example. code.google.com is a subdomain of google.com, mail.yahoo.com is a subdomain of yahoo.com.

Edit:

.co.uk is a second level domain. While it's a popular choice, it is really just a subdomain of .uk

Comment: Thanks, but as my question might suggest, I know these terms. :)